# Js regex for UAE Mobile Number

Tags: javascript, regex

Validate UAE mobile number using js regex.
Mobile No- +971 XXXXXXXXX (+971 and 9 digits after it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  The snippet below works for me:

  let mystring = '+971333344550';
    let reg = /\+971([\d]{9})/;
    let matches = mystring.match(reg);
    if (matches.length>0) {
        console.log('the number if valid');
    }
```